# Is it possible to choose the right rows in an ordered sequence of events without loops?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector

example row:

```
B1
S1
B2
B3/S2
B4
B5
B6/S4
S3
```

Rules:

- A row can be B (buy), S (sell) or both
- It is known which sell belongs to which buy and viceversa
- buys are ordered, sells are possibly not ordered
- When a buy has no matching sell, all the subsequent buys are discarded
- we want all the buy rows such that if there is a sell for that row, all the buy rows from that point up to the respective sell row are discarded.

This can be done with a simple loop, that skips the overlapping buys, but trying to implement this with vectors has been challenging and I am wondering if it is possible?

The most promising method I tried was padding the index of the buy and backfilling the indexes of the sell, and making sense of the possible combinations, although I am not sure they can give a unique view of the state...

Output from example would be:

```
B1
B2
B4
```

Comment: can you add your intended output?

Comment: I added it, and slightly tweaked the example otherwise the output would have been just B1, which reminded to specify what happens when there isn't a sell

Comment: Your problem sounds very sequential.  The idea behind `numpy` vectors is to look at the task as a whole.  Almost in a parallel fashion where you don't care which element is processed first.

Comment: You are right, however the number of possibilities of overlapping that takes place is finite, I wish I knew a tool that allowed me to graph all of them by specifiyng the rules. It might be that there is a core set of sequences that can't be discerned without iteration, so the best you could do is to reduce to it with vectorized operations, and then iterate over the smallest set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion, using `pandas`. I dont know if it is more efficient than what you are doing, but if the goal is to avoid looping, I think this will do it.

I will just assume your buy/sell-data can be split into two dataframes, one for buys and one for sells. I also add a 'time' column to each frame. I.e. when is the order to buy/sell, placed. Putting your data in a dataframe and the splitting this into the two abovementioned dataframes is probably an easy exercise, but I will skip it.

```
import pandas as pd

# Your data split into two frames (for instance, in df_buy, num=2, would be equivalent 
# to B2 occuring at the second, zero-indexed, time-step)
df_buy = pd.DataFrame({'Num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                       'Time': [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
# S1, S2, S4, S3 happening at time 1, 3, 6 and 7
df_sell = pd.DataFrame({'Num':[1, 2, 4, 3],
                        'Time': [1, 3, 6, 7]})

# Merge buy/sell to find all possible trades
df_trades = pd.merge(df_buy, df_sell, on='Num', suffixes=['_Buy', '_Sell'])
# Order all trades according to which time they would happen, i.e. time_sell.
# (or perhaps at max(time_sell, time_buy)?)
df_trades.sort_values(by='Time_Sell', inplace=True)

# Only trades that happen in increasing order would be allowed. So we filter
# out the trades that happen in decreasing order (ie. trade 3. cannot come 
# after trade 4)
df_final = df_trades[df_trades['Num'].sub(df_trades['Num'].shift(), fill_value=0)>=0]

# Here we have Num = 1, 2, 4 i.e. B1/S1, B2/S2 and B4/S4
Out[11]: 
   Num  Time_Buy  Time_Sell
0    1         0          1
1    2         2          3
3    4         4          6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however this doesn't take into account the case where you have a long trade, and short trades in between. If you sort by `time_sell` (or `max`, it doesn't matter in this case) then the longer trade appears after the shorter ones, and since its index is lower, it will be discarded.

Comment: OK. I suspected there might be cases i did not cover. With such a short time series it is difficult to come up with an answer that covers it all. But I get that its difficult to include a data series that cover everything.